# Unable to solve unhandled exception in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c

I was asked to create a linked list to create and display polynomials,
however the code skips to the exponent part without accepting the coefficient part and throws an unhandled exception -- an access violation for trying to write in `0xCDCD`. (I am very new to programming so please go easy on me while explaining what needs to be done).

#### The Code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>
    struct node
    {
        int coeff, expo;
        struct node* next;
    };

    struct node*head,*temp,*save;
    void create(int x);
    void display(); 
    void main()
    {   
      int  n=0,ch=0;
      printf("enter the highest degree of the polynomial you want to create");
      scanf_s("%d", &n);
      printf("\nenter the polynomial (coefficeint followed by the exponential of variable in descending order)");
      create(n);
      printf("\nthe polynomial now is");
      display();
    }

    void create(int x)
    {
      printf("\n enter degree %d(coeffecient)", x);
      printf("\n enter degree %d(exponent)", x);

      head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
      if (head == NULL)
      {
        printf("\n cannot allocate memory");
      }
      else
      {
        scanf_s("%d", head->coeff);
        scanf_s("%d", head->expo);
      }

      save = head;
      while (x>0)
      {
        save->next = temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
            printf("\n cannot allocate memory");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n enter degree %d(coeffecient)", x-1);
            printf("\n enter degree %d(exponent)", x-1);
            scanf_s("%d", head->coeff);
            scanf_s("%d", head->expo);
            save = temp;
            x--;
        }
      } 
    }

    void display()
    {
      temp = head;
      while(temp!=NULL)
      {
        printf("\n%dx^%d", temp->coeff, temp->expo);
        temp = temp->next;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you compiling with a C++ compiler? `head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` should return an error. Also, you dont need `temp` and `save`, head is enough to mantain the list.

Comment: @P__J__ as i am very new to the site i do not understand what you mean by that could you please elaborate?

Comment: @DavidRanieri I use the local windows debugger for most my programs since i only do light programming. Here however, I have tried running with head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); only for the output to be the same .I did not want to accidentally loose the initial address so i mostly let head be untouched .

Comment: `scanf_s` wants pointers, should be `scanf_s("%d", &head->coeff);` and `scanf_s("%d", &head->expo);`.... _I did not want to accidentally loose the initial address so i mostly let head be untouched_ mmm ... is easier to accidentally loose the address using your approach.

Comment: @DavidRanieri oh my bad i will keep it in mind most people in my class do the same and cite the very same reason that head should mostly be left untouched to preserve address i will certainly try to do more research on this

Comment: @SwarupMohapatra The last `node` in the list has `next` left unitialized, while the `display` loop assumes that it will be `NULL`.

Comment: @dxiv thank you very much this right here is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one bug:

```
scanf_s("%d", head->coeff);
scanf_s("%d", head->expo);
```

needs to be

```
scanf_s("%d", &head->coeff);
scanf_s("%d", &head->expo);
```

To make sure you're passing a pointer to a value you want to be filled in.

You also need to set new elements' `next` to `NULL` so you can traverse your list.  `malloc` does not give you cleared memory and IIRC VS will deliberately set allocated memory to a dummy value in debug mode to help drive out the bug you are encountering.

Comment: thank you very much the warnings have reduced but now there is an access violation present at printf("\n%dx^%d", temp->coeff, temp->expo); as you did say a few bugs were removed :D